# Displaying Current Position For Paint Program in Python

Tags: python, position, pygame, paint

I am currently adding my final touch to my paint program I have been creating using pygame and python 2.7.5.  The final thing I would like to add is a current position display.  I am just wondering about how I would do this.  I know how to get the current mouse position but I just do not know how to display it in my program.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pygame.font`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) module to display text in your window.

Example:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,100))

cur_x, cur_y = 0,0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            cur_x, cur_y = event.pos

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    coord_message = "position: x={}, y={}:".format(cur_x, cur_y)
    coord_label = font.render(coord_message, 1, (255,0,0))
    screen.blit(coord_label, (50, 10))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Result:

[image]